# Click on the link that point to twitter return ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE error

Tags: html, twitter

I've have simple link:

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/jcubic" target="_blank">...</a>
```

I use it on my CodePens to link to my profile on Twitter. Here is a base pen that I link to other pens. https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/WZjbgq?editors=0010 I use it for a long time, and now when I've checked. The link doesn't work.
I've got an error that the server blocked my request and I've got the error `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE`

I've tried to use `rel="noreferrer noopener"` but have no effect. I'm not able to open links that point to Twitter.

Does anybody know what is happening and how to fix it? The only way to visit twitter is to copy-paste the URL and open it in a new tab.

I use Fedora GNU/Linux and Google Chrome.

**EDIT:**

Weird is that it's only happened in the CodePen iframe. I can open Twitter links just fine when in debug mode.

I can report this to CodePen support but if you know why it's happening I will be able to why it's happening and maybe provide a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem with links to instagram from codepen

Comment: @Yukulélé forget to add the answer that Codepen support has given me, use `target="top"` on link.